# Не устанавливается Anaconda

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

Не устанавливается Анаконда с третьим питоном на 64 разрядную систему. В конце инсталляции выдает ошибку failed to create anaconda menus

Имя пользователя не менял с покупки компа, user.

Подскажите, что надо проверить/настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда, ларчик просто открывался. 
Во время установки НЕ нужно ставить галочку напротив "Add Anaconda to my path enviroment variable". При этом следите, чтобы директория установки содержала только латинские буквы и НЕ содержала пробелы.